# building dictionary to be JSON encoded - python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a list of class objects. Each object needs to be added to a dictionary so that it can be json encoded. I've already determined that I will need to use the json library and `dump` method. The objects look like this:

```
class Metro:

    def __init__(self, code, name, country, continent,
                 timezone, coordinates, population, region):
        self.code = code #string
        self.name = name #string
        self.country = country #string
        self.continent = continent #string
        self.timezone = timezone #int
        self.coordinates = coordinates #dictionary as {"N" : 40, "W" : 88}
        self.population = population #int
        self.region = region #int
```

So the json will look like this:

```
{
    "metros" : [
        {
            "code" : "SCL" ,
            "name" : "Santiago" ,
            "country" : "CL" ,
            "continent" : "South America" ,
            "timezone" : -4 ,
            "coordinates" : {"S" : 33, "W" : 71} ,
            "population" : 6000000 ,
            "region" : 1
        } , {
            "code" : "LIM" ,
            "name" : "Lima" ,
            "country" : "PE" ,
            "continent" : "South America" ,
            "timezone" : -5 ,
            "coordinates" : {"S" : 12, "W" : 77} ,
            "population" : 9050000 ,
            "region" : 1
        } , {...
```

Is there a simple solution for this? I've been looking into dict comprehension but it seems it will be very complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dict comprehension will not be very complicated.

```
import json

list_of_metros = [Metro(...), Metro(...)]

fields = ('code', 'name', 'country', 'continent', 'timezone',
          'coordinates', 'population', 'region',)

d = {
    'metros': [
        {f:getattr(metro, f) for f in fields}
        for metro in list_of_metros
    ]
}
json_output = json.dumps(d, indent=4)
```

Comment: there seems to be trouble in resolving the `f`, `metro`, `fields`, and `list_of_metros` variables in `d`. Could it be because I'm using a 3.3.4 interpreter?

Comment: @user2079802, There was a typo (redundant `f`) in a dict comprehension. I fixed it. The code can be run both in Python 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: that's perfect and surprisingly elegant

Comment: @anuragal, Thank you for comment, but the class `Metro` does not inherit from Django `Model` class, and the question is not tagged [tag:django].